# django database cache doesn't store value

Tags: django, caching

I have a problem using the DatabaseCache in django in a view. It seems like I don't get access to the database cache and that storing new values in the cache doesn't worl.

In **settings.py** I have put the settings for the cache:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'caches',
        'TIMEOUT': 300,
    }
}
```

In my app **accounts** I have the following in my **views.py**:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from accounts.serializers import UserSerializer
from django.core.cache import cache, caches

@api_view(['GET'])
def current_user(request):
    print("all caches")
    print(caches.all())

    cache_value = cache.get("foo")
    print("cache_value")
    print(cache_value)

    cache.set("foo", "some cached value", 24*60*60)

    cache_value_after_set = cache.get("foo")
    print("cache_value_after_set")
    print(cache_value_after_set)

    serializer = UserSerializer(request.user)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

The problem is that the cache doesn't seem "to stick". The first time try to do cache.get("foo") it will obviously return None. And further down the  line when I do cache.get("foo") - after I have done cache.set - it returns the value it should. But when I call the view the second time, cache.get("foo") returns None.

The output from caches.all() is an empty dictionary so I guess the cache settings in **settings.py** aren't used somehow in **views.py**.

The output after the first and second calls to the views are:

```
all caches
dict_values([])
cache_value
None
cache_value_after_set
some cached value
```

and

```
all caches
dict_values([])
cache_value
some cached value
cache_value_after_set
some cached value
```

I.e. the results are identical and no cache is set.

The really strange thing is that the cache works when using **./manage.py shell** and I can store things in the database even though caches.all() sometimes returns an empty dictionary and sometimes not. When I do this I can see the caches appear in the caches table in mysql.

I am running Django 1.11

Do you have any ideas on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As above, you are getting cache in second output also when fetch by key and not getting when using caches.al()

Comment: I did a print out of caches.all() to show that it is empty. It doesn't really do anything. 

The problem is that the first print out of cache.get("foo") in the view always returns None. 

After cache.set("foo", "some cached value", 24*60*60) has been called, all calls to cache.get("foo") should return "some cached value"

Comment: but, in your second output of code in 3rd line, it is printing the cache before setting.

Comment: Yes, that is the whole point. 

I want to check if a cache value exists before I use it. And if it doesn't exists I will do some operations and save the result. This result should be available the next time the view is called

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am seeing the same thing in Django 3. I got the same code to work as expected using memcached, but when I try the database, some values are saved and others aren't.  There is not a discernible pattern.  All I'm caching are numbers.

Comment: False alarm. Figured out that `memcached` does not respect Django's default MAX_ENTRIES but the database caching scheme *does*, which is why so many of my values were not saved.